# A python script that searchs for a file in the entire computer

Tags: python, windows, file, search

I am envolved in a project and i want to make a system that the user inputs a string like "summer_photos" and then the python searchs in all the folders and files and subfolders all the way down the C: tree and returns the absolute path of the files containing the name inputed. If i input summer_photos it can return

C:/User/Images/Summer1990/summer_photos.zip

C:/User/Images/Summer1991/summer_photos.zip
and etc.

As i am a petty beginner in Python using Windows i thought asking the masters of programming arts in stock overflow would be helpful.

Comment: Look into [scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir).

Comment: What have you already tried? If you have some code you wrote, please update your question with that. It'll help people to suggest you an approach for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using os.walk() function

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/"):
   for name in files:
      if "summer_photos" in name:
         //add path to list
```

Comment: i dont know why did you unaccept this but if you are looking for speed os.scandir is better option it is also in standart modules if you are using python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

The [`walk` function in the `os` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) might be a good place to start. And keep in mind that checking every file name in the entire hard drive will take *forever*; consider limiting the search to a user-specified directory :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. and about the time, i dont mind if it takes less than two hours.